# How to add generic instance to list of generic objects

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an Interface IShape and abstract class Shape. Shape implements IShape. Shape has 2 children - Circle and Rectangle.
Also I have generic interface IDrawer where T:IShape. I have an abstract generic class BaseDrawer : IDrawer where T : IShape.

```
public interface IShape
    {
        double M1();
        double M2();
    }

public abstract class Shape : IShape
    {
        public abstract double M1();
        public abstract double M2();
    }

public class Circle : Shape
    {
    }

public class Rectangle: Shape
    {
    }

public interface IDrawer<T> where T:IShape
    {
        void Draw(T shape);
    }  

 public abstract class BaseDrawer<T> : IDrawer<T> where T : IShape
    {
       public abstract void Draw(T shape);
    }

public class CircleDrawer : BaseDrawer<Circle>
    {
        public override void Draw(Circle circle)
        {
        }
    }

public class RectangleDrawer : BaseDrawer<Rectangle>
        {
            public override void Draw(Rectangle rectangle)
            {
            }
        }
```

I have a list: `List<IDrawer<IShape>> Drawers { get; set; }`
When I'm trying to create an instance of CircleDrawer - `var drawer = new CircleDrawer();` - and add it to this list, I get an error: Cannot convert CircleDrawer to IDrawer.

What changes do I need to make to add instance of circleDrawer to this list?

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic covariance and contravariance here we go!

So you have something of type `CircleDrawer` which we can straightforwardly convert to `IDrawer<Circle>`. Let's see what happens

```
var list = new List<IDrawer<IShape>>();
IDrawer<Circle> drawer = new CircleDrawer(); // Completely reasonable cast.

list.Add(drawer); // This results in the error.
```

Okay, but why? That's because circle being a shape **does not** imply that a drawer of circles is a drawer of shapes. A conversion

```
IDrawer<IShape> shapeDrawer = drawer;
```

is illegal. What you're trying to do is actually impossible. A drawer of circles knows how to draw circles, not shapes. Let's say that the cast you're trying to do is legal. We add the drawer to the list.

```
list.Add(drawer);
```

and now somewhere else we take it out of the list and give it a shape:

```
IDrawer<IShape> drawer = list.First();
drawer.Draw(shape);
```

Is this correct? Well, it depends on the `shape`. If it is

```
IShape shape = new Circle();
```

then yeah, we're giving a circle to our `CircleDrawer`, everything is okay. But note that this line:

```
IShape shape = new Rectangle();

drawer.Draw(shape);
```

would also be legal. And it should be, giving an `IShape` object to `IDrawer<IShape>` seems reasonable. Feels like it should work. But it doesn't. You just called a `CircleDrawer.Draw(Circle shape)` method by giving it a rectangle in place of the circle. What's going to happen? This is not a situation any `CircleDrawer` would like to find itself in. Imagine if you were taught how to draw circles your whole life and suddenly someone gives you a rectangle to draw :O

So the type system disallows the `Add` on the list. Usually when this happens you can fix it by marking your generic type co- or contravariant. But in this case the thing you want to do is literally impossible and nonsensical - a collection of drawers of which the exact type you don't know is useless to you. You don't know what they can draw, so with every `Draw` call you're playing russian roulette and hoping the rectangle you just passed went to a `RectangleDrawer` not a `CircleDrawer`.

The only thing you could make happen is assing things the other way around - so let's say you have a `RectangleDrawer` and a `SquareDrawer`

```
class Rectangle : IShape {}

class Square : Rectangle {}

class RectangleDrawer : IDrawer<Rectangle> {}

class SquareDrawer : IDrawer<Square> {}
```

Then a collection of square drawers would be perfectly fine, and you might want to do something like

```
var list = new List<SquareDrawer>();

var squareDrawer = new SquareDrawer();
var rectangleDrawer = new RectangleDrawer();

list.Add(squareDrawer);
list.Add(rectangleDrawer);
```

And then you could use that list giving the drawers in it squares to draw. That makes sense, since being a `RectangleDrawer` implies that you can draw *any* rectangles, squares included.

The above lines will not compile however - you would have to mark your `IDrawer` contravariant.

```
interface IDrawer<in T> where T : IShape
{
    void Draw(T shape);
}
```

This tells the compiler that a `IDrawer<T>` can also draw `U` if `U : T`. It also disallows specifying `T` as a return type of any member methods.

More on covariance and contravariance can be found [in the MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about this for a second.

You're saying that a `CircleDrawer` is a type of `IDrawer<IShape>` since a `Circle` is a type of `IShape`.

But an `IDrawer<IShape>` is something that can draw an `IShape` - any `IShape`. Now a `CircleDrawer` can draw a Circle, but no other shape, so it is not an `IDrawer<IShape>`.

An `IDrawer<IShape>` however could in theory be an instance of an `IDrawer<Circle>`, since it can draw any shape, including a circle. To specify that formally, you'll have to use Covariance/Contravariance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance.

In your case, you'll have to create a `List<IDrawer<Circle>>` I'm afraid.

To show where things could go wrong if you were allowed to treat a `CircleDrawer` as `IDrawer<IShape>` consider the following code:

```
IDrawer<IShape> drawer = new CircleDrawer();
drawer.Draw(new Rectangle()); //Throws exception - a circle drawer can't draw a rectangle
```