# Add inherited generic class to dictionary with generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I am trying to add to a Dictionary where the value is a class with two generics. The two generics must derive from an abstract class, `BaseEntity`:

```cs
internal abstract class BaseEntity
{
    ...
}

internal class DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult> where T : BaseEntity where TResult : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}

internal class DataEtlContext : IDataEtlContext
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, DataEtlModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity>> models = new Dictionary<Type, DataEtlModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity>>();

    public void RegisterModelType<T, TResult>() where T : BaseEntity where TResult : BaseEntity
    {
        models.Add(typeof(T), new DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult>());
    }
}
```

I would expect this to be valid since the `RegisterModelType` method ensures that `T` and `TResult` both derive from the `BaseEntity` class by nature of the type contraints.

However, I am receiving the following error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from '...DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult>' to '...DataEtlModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity>'.

The error lint is on the following code:

```cs
new DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult>()
```

Can anyone explain why this is, and propose a possible solution?

Comment: I's obviously not valid as DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult> is not derived from DataEtlModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check [co- and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

You haven't shown us the definition of your `DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult>` class, but let's imagine that it has a method with signature:

```
void Accept(T t);
```

(any method accepting `T` as a parameter will do).

Now let's also imagine `DerivedEntity` inheriting from `BaseEntity`. And now let's change our universe to one in which `models.Add(typeof(T), new DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult>());` is valid code and call `RegisterModelType<DerivedEntity, TAnything>`, where `TAnything` can be, well, anything deriving from `BaseEntity`.

So an object of type `DataEtlModelRegistration<DerivedEntity, TAnything>` is now in the dictionary under the key `typeof(DerivedEntity)`. Let's try to extract it:

```
DataEtlModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity> model = models[typeof(DerivedEntity)];
```

Now, since `entity` is of type `DataEtlModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity>`, this code should work (provided `BaseEntity` has an available default ctor):

```
model.Accept(new BaseEntity());
```

Bang, the type system is broken. You've passed `BaseEntity` to a method that accepts `DerivedEntity` as a parameter. `BaseEntity` *is not* `DerivedEntity`, you cannot do that.

Because of that, generic types are invariant by default. Basically it means that, e.g. `List<DerivedEntity>` is not a `List<BaseEntity>`, because you shouldn't be able to add any `BaseEntity` to a list of `DerivedEntity`s. So, if your class contains a method accepting `T` (or `TResult`, the same logic applies) as a parameter, you *cannot* do what you're trying to do.

However, if there is no such method, then you could make your types covariant by using an interface:

```
interface IModelRegistration<out T, out TResult> where T : BaseEntity where TResult : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}

internal class DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult> : IModelRegistration<T, TResult> where T : BaseEntity where TResult : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}
```

Basically you're telling the compiler "Hey, this interface will never accept any objects of the generic types, it only returns them". That code will fail to compile if the interface `IModelRegistration` contains a method with `T` or `TResult` as its parameter. Now it's legal to say:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, IModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity>> models = new Dictionary<Type, IModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity>>();

models.Add(typeof(DerivedEntity), new DataEtlModelRegistration<DerivedEntity, DerivedEntity>());
```

You will be able to extract an object from the dictionary as an instance of the `IModelRegistration` interface.

```
IModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity> model = models[typeof(DerivedEntity)];
```

There's no way for you to break the type system now, because we know for a fact that the `IModelRegistration` interface has no methods that would accept an object of any of its type parameters.

You can also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690945/how-to-add-generic-instance-to-list-of-generic-objects/52691129#52691129), where I gave an explanation for how contravariance works.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot inherit the type definitions. Even if `T` and `TResult` inherit from BaseEntity it doesn't mean that `List<BaseEntity> = new List<T>` works. Otherwise you could do this `List<object> list = new List<String>()`. You can create `List<BaseEntity>` and fill it with `T` and `TResult` objects, though.

You can either

```
models.Add(typeof(T), new DataEtlModelRegistration<BaseEntity, BaseEntity>());
```

and insert `T`and `TResult` objects into the DataEtlModelRegistration or

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult>> models = new Dictionary<Type, DataEtlModelRegistration<T, TResult>>();
```

if it is important that the objects' types matter.

Answer (score -1):

DataEtlModelRegistration is not derived from DataEtlModelRegistration even if generic parameters have some relationship. You can't avoid it for classes. It is possible to workaround with interfaces, since they support co-variance, but I am not sure interfaces will work for you, since you may need data and method implementations in those classes.

A possible alternative is to have non-generic base class for DataEtlModelRegistration with all necessary virtual methods (or even interface). And the dictionary above will have it as the value type parameter.