# Generic class with matching generic parameters not valid base class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

Why is in the below example `Base<BaseResult<bool, object>, bool, object>` not a valid base class for `Concrete<object>`? `Base<BaseResult<bool, object>, bool, object>` is base to `SpecializedBase<bool, object>`, and `SpecializedBase<bool, object>` seems like a proper base for `Concrete<object>`?

```
public abstract class Base<TResult, TOutcome, TOutput>
        where TResult : BaseResult<TOutcome, TOutput>
        where TOutput : class
    {
    }

    public class BaseResult<TOutcome, TOutput>
    {
    }

    public abstract class SpecializedBase<TResult, TOutput> :
        Base<SpecializedResult<TOutput>, bool, TOutput>
        where TOutput : class
    {
    }

    public class SpecializedResult<TOutput> : BaseResult<bool, TOutput>
    {
    }

    public class Concrete<TOutput> : 
        SpecializedBase<SpecializedResult<TOutput>, TOutput>
        where TOutput : class
    {
    }

    static class Program {
        static void main()
        {
            // #1: works
            SpecializedBase<SpecializedResult<object>, object> obj;

            obj = new Concrete<object>();

            // #2: works
            Base<SpecializedResult<object>, bool, object> obj2;

            obj2 = new Concrete<object>();

            // #3: doesn't work:
            // Cannot implicitly convert type 'TypeTest.Concrete<object>' to 'TypeTest.Base<TypeTest.BaseResult<bool, object>, bool, object>'
            Base<BaseResult<bool, object>, bool, object> obj3;

            obj3 = new Concrete<object>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to resolve the type step by step.

`Concrete<object>` **is** `SpecializedBase<SpecializedResult<object>, object>`.
`SpecializedBase<SpecializedResult<object>, object>` **is** `Base<SpecializedResult<object>, bool, object>`.

And that's it. `Base` inherits directly from `Object`, so ultimately the least derived type is `Base<TResult, TOutcome, TOutput>` with `TResult` set to `SpecializedResult<object>`, `TOutcome` to `bool` and `TOutput` to `object`. This type is *invariant* and thus `Base<SpecializedResult<object>, bool, object>` **is not** `Base<BaseResult<bool, object>, bool, object>`.

You can find more on generic variance [in the MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690945/how-to-add-generic-instance-to-list-of-generic-objects) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445631/still-confused-about-covariance-and-contravariance-in-out) (and probably a thousand other places as well, it's a notoriously complicated concept to wrap your head around).